# words in regular expressions

Tags: grep

What pattern could I used to find any occurrence of a word of n length in a line?

I thought of doing:

```
grep -ni ' '[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]' ' filename
```

But this doesn't take care of matching a 6-letter word at the beginning or end of the line.
Is there a way to match a `space` or the `beginning/end of a line`? Also is there a method to look for the pattern [a-z] n times, instead of typing them n times?

I know that `^` is for beginning of line and `$` for end of line.

For example some pseudo script of what I want:

```
#match a word of n length(n consecutive letters)
grep -ni ^ OR [:space:][a-z]{n consecutive times}[:space:] OR $ filename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU grep has the beginning-of-word and end-of-word matching operators `\<` and `\>`

Combined with the `{N}` repetition operator from Extended Regular Expression, that means you can use

```
egrep -i '\<[a-z]{6}\>'
```

Or, a little harder to read but perhaps more portable, you can use the alternation operator `|` for your "OR"s and group them with parentheses:

```
egrep -i '(^|[[:space:]])[a-z]{6}([[:space:]]|$)'
```

You should be aware of a behavioral difference between these approaches. Word boundaries occur at punctuation, not just spaces, so if you use `\<` and `\>` (or the perl-ish `\b` and `\b` which are more recent additions to GNU grep), then you will also match words at the end of a sentence, followed by a dot instead of a space.

And that might be good, but that bad side is you'll match `wouldn't` too, because `wouldn` is 6 letters and apostrophe is a word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

This regex:

```
\b\w{6}\b
```

... matches a word boundary (which can either be the transition between a word character like `[a-z]` and a non-word character like `' '`, or the beginning or end of a line), followed by six word characters, followed by another word boundary. You'll need `egrep` or `grep -E`, since `{6}` is extended regex syntax:

```
egrep -ni '\b\w{6}\b' filename
```

You could replace `\w` with `[a-z]` if you don't want to match digits and underscores (which `\w` does).

Comment: grep isn't perl; why not `\<` and `\>`? They look nicer than `\b` and you're doing something non-portable anway.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I happen to be more used to `\b` (as a Pythonista, not a Perlmonger), so that came to mind first. I won't bother adding to my answer, since yours (upvoted) covers it.

Answer (score 1):

Most grep implementations have a `-w` option whether the matching substring is at the  beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character, or at the end  of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the  underscore, at least in the implementation of grep that I'm using.

So:

```
$ egrep -wi '[a-z]{6}' filename
```

This saves you from requiring word boundaries, which in my experience are not always supported by grep.  (The `-i` option makes the match case-insensitive.)

We use `egrep` instead of `grep` to evaluate "Extended" regular expressions rather than "Basic" ones.  Pretty much every grep out there will understand both of these.  Avoid PCRE (`grep -P`) if you're interested in portability.